# How to use Umbraco7 as API with Vue.js?

Tags: frontend, backend, umbraco, umbraco7

I am just learning Umbraco and I have a basic template that has just one alias. What kind of controller should I code for it? Could you please give me an example to reach my alias from js frameworks?

Comment: Tolga, there are some good resources on the internet to learn about Umbraco - take a look at these resource first so that things will make more sense to you. This will help you asking better questions. Some resources that I can recommend are as follows;
https://umbraco.tv/
https://our.umbraco.com/forum/
https://umbraco.com/training/online-cms-training-courses/
https://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2020
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PmAYWmH9BhE
https://www.jondjones.com/learn-umbraco-cms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I have used UmbracoCms.RestApi extension from NuGet and solved my problem.

You can use default endpoints to get properties that you have created in Umbraco Cms before with that extension. There is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLGK4eaqf1M) about that.